# How to avoid "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error in React?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, axios

I have a react app and I'm trying to make an Axios GET call from the backend. It returns the following Error

```
"ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"
```

In the Postman, **it works when I disable the SSL** from the Postman App. How can I disable it from the React app or from the Browser?

I have already tried hundreds of ways to get a self-signed certificate to my localhost and none of them were worked.

Comment: hello @davidJohns,  I have this same issue, all the fixes I have found are all in Mac or Linux, so far I could not find any solution for windows PC + chromium browsers. somehow I feel chrome is accessing a different certificate from the one in my react project.

I have tried everything still didnt work.

Comment: @emekaokoli try typing "thisisunsafe" on your keyboard when you get the error page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do couple of things here:-

1. Modifying the start script attribute
2. Generating valid ssl keys and configuring for create react app.

Please refer to think [link](https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-configure-https-localhost/) for more details

Hope it helps, Thanks

Comment: Please can you help with "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" for Windows PC?

Comment: @emekaokoli based on the search i think this link should work for you:- https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-https-for-local-development-for-react-angular-and-node-fdfaf69693cd  please see if it works